# How to stop a full screen default activity on android?

Tags: android

I have made my android application as the default application.

Now i rebooted my tablet while the application was running.

So when the tablet restarts, my application starts and there is no way to stop the application. So i cant get to the home screen.

How can i clear the default activity as i cant see the home screen and cant goto settings?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot your device into safe mode. This will disable third-party applications and should return you to your normal home screen, where you can go into settings and remove the app.

Or, try uninstalling it from the command line (`adb uninstall` or `ant uninstall`, depending on whether or not you are using Ant for building the project). That should work, though I have not tried it for removing the current default home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sandip  you can fetch  the your Application Proceess id and you can kill by following

use it may be it is useful for you .. i m not sure..

```
System.out.println("Process is now Kill : "+android.os.Process.myPid());
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```